# Matlab book recommendation

Tags: books, applied-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

Which book or books do you recommend that cover advanced engineering topics and problem solving using matlab?

I already finished a very good introductory book and i want something more advanced.

Do you think it's better to read a book that covers several topics or search for the topics i'm interested in and then explore the methods applied on them?

I'm more interested in applied mathematics, algorithms, computation and engineering.
I study product design and engineering if this helps.

Comment: which book have you already gone thru?

Comment: @Suvrit , Matlab - a practical approach (Stormy Attaway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of some books that you might find useful.

1. Introduction to Scientific Computing by Charles F. Van Loan
2. Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan (uses Matlab notation, but contains a wealth of material)
3. You might also benefit from trying to extend the methods in "Numerical Recipes" to Matlab. They have some information about that [here](http://www.nr.com/nr3_matlab.html)
4. Have a look at "Numerical Computing with Matlab" by Cleve Moler (the guy who created Matlab); [check it out here](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/chapters.html)

But really, the best way to learn more is to actually have an application or targeted problem at hand. Then, while attempting to solve your problem, you will gradually pick up the tricks of the trade. While doing that, perhaps people at the mathworks file exchange or over at stackoverflow might be able to help you further. Happy experimenting!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, for learning more advanced topics and techniques, the best strategy is to talk to people and read their code.  In contrast to the foundations of a language and method, extensions are difficult to neatly organize, and books that attempt it either fail to capture essences (doing little more than enumerating) or become so vast that they are very difficult to use (at which point MATLAB's built-in help becomes a better tool).  For this reason, **I recommend to find topics that interest you and explore them from a broad perspective, nonexclusively including MATLAB-specific objectives.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's advanced enough for you, but my favourite Matlab book for teaching engineering applications is Recktenwald's "Numerical Methods with MATLAB"
(http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/nmm/).  It has lots of exercises, code samples, and resources on the author's web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you've never used Matlab or programmed before *Matlab A Practival Approach* by Attaway is useful and complete for an introduction.

More advanced would be *Matlab Guide* by Higham and Higham.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Matlab Help feature** installed, then reading the help section for various commands is extremely useful. Their documentation is so extensive that one invariably lays his hands on what one tries to find. All one really needs is a bit of programming language understanding, just to see how arguments are passed in functions.

Also, each command is summarized along with examples, so that also teaches writing optimized codes. For example, instead of using *for* loops, it is better (computationally faster) to use matrices. This is illustrated in the examples.

Moreover, this is cheap (provided you have a Matlab licence) since the help files come with the installation!